# Create Group Email from Labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, contacts-group

When I receive an email from a prospective client in my Gmail inbox, I place a specific label on it according to the query.

Is there a way to create a **group** email easily to send out to all recipients who are under the same label? In the past I have had to bring up the label, hand write the email address down  and manually create a group in contacts and add each email address to be able to send out an email to all recipients in a particular label.

Answer (score 5):

Presently, there's no way to compose a new group email based on conversations in a label.

You can however, create a Contact group from an email message, rather than navigating to the Contacts page.

---

1. Compose a new message in Gmail and enter the email addresses of all intended recipients in the `To` field.

   - Alternatively, Navigate to your label, select a conversation with all recipients and click `Reply all`, and ensure all email recipients are in the `To` field (`cc` or `bcc` will also work).
2. Click `To` to select contacts.

[image: Click To]

3. From the pop up, click `Save as group...` and enter a name for your group.

[image: Confirm Group]

4. Save

[image: Save Group]

5. Reload Gmail
6. Compose a new message. In the `To` field, enter the name of your group and select the group from the autofill results.

[image: Demo Group Ready]

---

Caveats:

- If you want to remove members from or add members to the Group you created this way, you will have to do that via Google Contacts. Or, you can follow the steps above to create a new group with the new composition of recipients.

Comment: This gives an "Unable to save group" error message for me :/

Comment: 2019 and getting the following message: "Can't edit labels" when clicking apply after selecting the label I want to add the contacts to.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way.

Go to Contacts.
Select New Group:

[image]

At the top of the nav, click on the 'Add to' icon:

[image]

Then just paste the email addresses that you've copied from the 'Reply To All' in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Create and populate the contact label**

1. Go to contacts.google.com
2. Select menu on left and click "Add Label"
3. Select a contact
4. Click on the '...' menu on the right, and select the label you created.

**Send email to contact label**

1. Once the you have all your contacts, go back to the contact menu and select your label
2. Hover over the picture or letter symbol next to the first contact
3. A checkbox will appear. Click it to check that contact
4. An empty check box will appear at the top middle of the page. Click it to select all contacts in the label
5. Click on the mail icon to open up an email.

The only feature I would like to see is to be able to put the contacts on the "Cc:" or "Bcc:" line instead of the "To:" line.

Answer (score -1):

You can inspect the page using developer tools in chrome, get the table element as html, then use sublime text to regex find with email="(.*?)@(.*?)" then you can hit 'find all' and cut out all the email address and paste them into a new document. Then in sublime text go in the menu edit -> permute lines -> unique and it will remove duplicates. Then you can copy the list into a new email.