# Making a Contact Group in Gmail from an email

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts-group

I received an email with dozens of people in the cc: field.  I would like to convert this list of addresses to a contact group in Gmail.  Is there a simple way of doing this without writing a script or entering each person into the group from the "Other Contacts" list?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the Gmail conversation/message.
2. At the right of the recipients fields, click the "Show details" dropdown button.
3. Copy the list of addresses.
4. Go to the Google / Gmail contacts manager.
5. If the Google Contacts Preview UI is shown, change to the old Contacts UI.
6. Create a new group.
7. Click the "Add to " group name  button.
8. Paste the list of addresses.
9. Click the Add button.

For an alternate method, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74913/88163) to [Create Group Email from Labels](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74907/88163)

Comment: I tried this now and had a problem with the new interface. I had to switch to the old contact list to import the addresses in bulk.

Comment: This is a protected question, and I can't post the full answer with nice pictures and etc. unfortunately. The caveat with the new interface is to choose an option to _import_ contacts in Google Contacts: 1. Open Google Contacts and make label, 2. Select label in the list, 3. Click 'Import' on the panel below labels, 4. Now, we don't have a csv file, so we choose 'Create Multiple Contacts' instead, 5. Copy-paste the list of addresses in the field from Gmail conversation/message like explained in this answer.

Comment: @Wormer Post a "basic" answer and once you get some reputation on this site you could enhance it with screenshots, etc.

Comment: @Ruben There is no way for me to post any kind of answer to this question, despite the fact that I got some reputation on other Stack Exchange sites. This all doesn't matter much since the information I wanted to share with people is there and hopefully not that hard to find. Thank you.